# Meteor collection.insert callback issues

Tags: meteor

According to the Meteor documentation....

> `collection.insert(doc, [callback])`
>
> **callback** Function
>
> Optional. If present, called with an error object as the first argument and the _id as the second.

...then later down...

> On the server, if you don't provide a callback, then insert blocks until the database acknowledges the write, or throws an exception if something went wrong. If you do provide a callback, insert returns immediately. Once the insert completes (or fails), the callback is called with error and result arguments, same as for methods.

Which is it, error and _id or error and result?  I do have Meteor.methods that are firing their callbacks correctly with error, result available to the scope.

I just can't get the callback to work correctly on a collection.insert(doc, [callback])

Either way I can't get my callback to register anything?

```
function insertPost(args) {
  this.unblock;
  if(args) { 
    post_text = args.text.slice(0,140);
    var ts = Date.now();  
    Posts.insert({
      post: post_text,
      created: ts
    }, function(error, _id){
      // or try function(error, result) and still get nothing 
      // console.log('result: ' + result);
      console.log('error: ' + error);
      console.log('_id: ' + _id); //this._id doesn't work either
    });

  }
  return;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?  I have been up since 2 am coding...6 pm my time zone...I am blurry, so I might (probably) be missing something quite obvious.

Cheers
Steeve

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This was a bug, fixed in the next release.  Now, if you provide a callback to `insert`, it will be called with `error` and `result` arguments, where `result` is the ID of the new document, or null if there's an error.

Comment: Is this still a bug? I'm faced with the same issue Steeve Cannon was getting. Cannot get anything to fire in the second argument.

Answer (score 6):

Since this is serverside code you can just do:

```
var id = Posts.insert({data}); // will block until insert is complete
```

and the id will be available.

Comment: thank you, that is what I went with.  Though I want to do more of a callback style in the future. They said it will be avail in the future for those interested.