# Meteor Collection.insert() not returning Id

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, observable, angular-meteor

I'm trying to get the Id of the new insert so I can push the Id onto another collection.

According to this post =>
[Meteor collection.insert callback to return new id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18785204/meteor-collection-insert-callback-to-return-new-id]) and this post => [Meteor collection.insert callback issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10507216/meteor-collection-insert-callback-issues]), I should be able to

```
return Collection.insert(obj);
```

and it will return the ID of the newly inserted data to my client.

Instead I'm getting an Observable like this:

```
    {_isScalar: false}
    _isScalar: false
    __proto__:
       constructor: f Object()
       hasOwnProperty: f hasOwnProperty()
    //many other object properties
```

The documentation seems pretty clear that I should be getting the ID in return. Is this a bug? https://docs.meteor.com/api/collections.html#Mongo-Collection-insert]

My version of meteor is 1.4.4.5...
I've been working on this issue for a few days and I've tried getting the ID many different ways, nothing I've tried results in the ID.

Here's my full code for reference:

**Server:**

```
submitStuff: function(data): string{
        var loggedInUser = Meteor.user();
        if (!loggedInUser || !Roles.userIsInRole(loggedInUser,['user','admin'])){
            throw new Meteor.Error("M504", "Access denied");
        } else {
            try{
                let insertedData = null;
                const model: MyModel[] = [{
                    data.stuff //bunch of data being inserted
                  }];
              model.forEach((obj: MyModel) => {
                insertedData = Collection.insert(obj);
              });
              return insertedData;
           } catch(e) {
                throw new Meteor.Error(e + e.reason, "|Throw new error|");
           }
        }
    },
```

**Client:**

```
Meteor.call('submitData', data, (error, value) => {
        if(error){
            this.errors.push(error + error.reason + "|new Error code|");
        }
        else{
            Meteor.call('userPushId', value, (error) => { //this pushes Id onto the second collection
                if(error){
                    this.errors.push(error + error.reason + "|new Error code|");
                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: You really don’t need to/shouldn’t send the I’d back to the client to be written to another collection. You can just as easily put the write to the second collection immediately after the first. Meteor awaits database calls by default so sequentially written dB writes/reads happen sequentially.

Comment: Yeah, I was trying to/wanting to do it that way. I was merely testing out sending it to the client.. Really grasping at straws

Comment: So the issue is that the insert is not returning id in general? Can you successfully log the id to the console on the server?

Comment: Correct. I've only been able to log an Observable from the insert method... I tried using the callback in the second argument as well. The callback wouldn't log anything to the console.

Comment: Oh. I think i see what’s what. I’ll write a solution when I get to a comp. if you change your foreach to map you should get an array of ids. I’ll look more into it in an hour or so

Comment: I don't think it's the forEach. I tried removing the foreach and inserting the data without sticking it into an array first. Same thing. Returning an object instead of an Id :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164447/discussion-between-xerotolerant-and-rager).

Comment: Just left my comp, will return in a couple hours

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, so after searching around I realized I'm using angular-meteors rxjs package to create a `MongoObservable` when creating a collection instead of Mongo's regular collection.

Because I'm using `MongoObservable` and trying to invoke `.insert()` on that, the return is a bit different then a regular Mongo Collection and will return an Observable instead of the Id. [Documentation Here](https://angular-meteor.com/api/meteor-rxjs/latest/ObservableCollection)

If you add a `.collection` after the collection name you will get the Id in return like so:

```
submitStuff: function(data): string{
    var loggedInUser = Meteor.user();
    if (!loggedInUser || !Roles.userIsInRole(loggedInUser,['user','admin'])){
        throw new Meteor.Error("M504", "Access denied");
    } else {
        try{
            let id = new Mongo.ObjectID();
            const model: MyModel[] = [{
                data.stuff //bunch of data being inserted
                _id: 
              }];
          model.forEach((obj: MyModel) => {
            insertedData = Collection.collection.insert(obj); //added .collection
          });
          return insertedData;
       } catch(e) {
            throw new Meteor.Error(e + e.reason, "|Throw new error|");
       }
    }
},
```

Answer (score 1):

**Server**

```
// ...

try {
   const myModels = [{ ...whatever }];

   // I'm using map so I return an array of id's. 
   //your forEach about technically should end up with only one id,
   // which is the last insertion

   const insertedDataIds = myModels.map(model => Collection.insert(model));
  // you can also write to the secondary location here with something like:
  const secondaryWrite = SecondaryCollection.insert({ something: insertedDataIds });

  return insertedDataId's
}
//...
```

**Client**

also I don't know if this is just a typo on stack but your `Meteor.call('submitData')` should be `Meteor.call('submitStuff')` but that is probably not your actual issue.

Comment: I'm wondering how this works in context of the insert method which is supposed to return a unique Id for the data that's inserted into the mongodb. does .map have it's own set of unique Id's ?

Comment: I console logged an undefined while using the above code.